# PostgreSQL Calculations Using Subselect Values

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery, alias, postgresql-9.3

Using PostgreSQL 9.3, I am trying to calculate some values based on the results of subselects from our email table. *The following is what I want to do*, which of course gives a SQL error since you can't reference alias values in the SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    email.key,
    email.col1,
    email.col2,
    (SELECT count(sent.subscriber_key) FROM sent WHERE sent.email_id = email.key) AS sent_count,
    (SELECT count(bounce.subscriber_key) FROM bounce WHERE bounce.email_id = email.key) AS bounce_count,
    ((bounce_count / sent_count) * 100) as bounce_pct
FROM
    email
ORDER BY 
    email.key
```

I have tried moving the subselect logic into the WITH clause:

```
WITH
    sent_tmp AS (SELECT count(sent.subscriber_key) as count FROM sent INNER JOIN email ON sent.send_id = email.key),
    bounce_tmp AS (SELECT count(bounce.subscriber_key) as count FROM bounce INNER JOIN email ON bounce.send_id = email.key)
SELECT 
    email.key,
    email.col1,
    email.col2,
    email.sent_date,
    sent_tmp.count,
    bounce_tmp.count,
    ((bounce_tmp.count / sent_tmp.count) * 100) as bounce_pct
FROM
    email,
    sent_tmp,
    bounce_tmp
ORDER BY 
    email.key
```

...and I have tried moving it into the FROM clause:

```
SELECT 
    email.key,
    email.col1,
    email.col2,
    sent_count,
    bounce_count,
    ((bounce_count / sent_count) * 100) as bounce_pct
FROM
    email,
    (SELECT count(sent.subscriber_key) FROM sent INNER JOIN email ON sent.send_id = email.key) AS sent_count,
    (SELECT count(bounce.subscriber_key) FROM bounce INNER JOIN email ON bounce.send_id = email.key) AS bounce_count
ORDER BY 
    email.key
```

...**but either way yields invalid sent and bounce numbers**.  (The numbers are all the same for each email.) I am probably not understanding the order of execution of the PostgreSQL query syntax, or the subselects are not being evaluated for each row of results from the email table.

If someone could kindly point me in the right direction and let me know what's possible, it would be appreciated! Am I missing some key syntax when moving the subselect logic into WITH or FROM? Do I need to use named variables? Functions?

I realize that it's possible to add another subselect which would re-count the subscriber_key column in both the sent and bounce tables, but I'm trying to avoid the recount for efficiency's sake.  (And readability, for that matter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to calculate the value in an outer query:

```
SELECT key, col1, col2, sent_count, bounce_count,
       100.0 * bounce_count / sent_count AS bounce_pct
FROM (SELECT key, col1, col2,
            (SELECT count(sent.subscriber_key)
             FROM sent
             WHERE sent.email_id = email.key
            ) AS sent_count,
            (SELECT count(bounce.subscriber_key)
             FROM bounce
             WHERE bounce.email_id = email.key
            ) AS bounce_count
      FROM email
     ) q
ORDER BY key;
```